# Problems with shutdown from command line

Tags: command-line, dell, shutdown

Whenever I attempt to shutdown my dell inspiron 1545 laptop from the command line with `sudo shutdown now`    I get the following error after the ubuntu shutdown screen closes:

```
Could not get system bus. Make sure message bus daemon is running! Message: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:no such file or directory
```

I have actually installed ubuntu several times on this laptop but always have this strange error. I checked out the directory `/var/run/dbus` and `system_bus_socket` is within that directory so I am a bit at a loss for ideas on why it won't recognize the existence of the socket. I can however shutdown from the GUI with no problems. Any thoughts on why the `sudo shutdown now` command isn't working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do  `sudo shutdown -h now`.

Also, `man shutdown` should be helpful.

Comment: Awesome! thank you. Such a simple fix. I am curious though, what is the purpose of shutting down and not powering off. I didn't have access to my bootloader or really anything other than that error screen. Is it just for debugging purposes?

Comment: Try to see `man shutdown` , it should help you :)